# Frame-by-frame PSNR using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to get a dump of the PSNR of every frame of a video using ffmpeg or ffprobe? So far all the options I've seen are for comparing two videos or getting the average across the whole video. If ffmpeg cannot do it, are there other softwares that can?

Edit: OK it seems like I misunderstood what PSNR is. I thought it was a measure of quality of an image, but it seems like it is a measure of quality between an original image and a compressed image.

Comment: Have you read the filter docs: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr

Comment: @Gyan I did, it says "Obtain the average, maximum and minimum PSNR (Peak Signal to Noise Ratio) between two input videos.", but I want to find it for a single video, and when I tried to input the same video twice as both inputs, the output stats file was just a bunch of zeros

Comment: ok it seems like I misunderstood what PSNR is, sorry